# DeskBand with WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, taskbar, deskband

It's been a few years after the last question here about `DeskBands`. So...

I've found this DeskBand called `My Dell`, all the current <s>bloatware</s> software from Dell is probably made with WPF.

Here is the DeskBand:

[image]

**Is it possible to use WPF to make that? or even just xaml?**

The only example I got it is from 2002 and uses WinForms.

**Why the CLOSE votes??? It's a simple and valid question!!!**

Comment: That's probably just an image.

Comment: Nop, when I MouseHover there is a glow effect. And there is a context menu.

Comment: That's probably just a second image.  And context menus are easy in any environment.  There is no reason to use WPF for this.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

> Is it possible to use WPF to make that?

Yes.

Comment: Well?  This isn't facebook, care to share?